# Avoiding duplicate values in my query

Tags: mysql

the following is my query

```
 SELECT 
        `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`hh_id` AS `hh_id`,
        `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`animalid` AS `animalid`,
        CONCAT(IFNULL(`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`tagsec`,
                        'Without Tag'),
                ' - ',
                `adggtnz`.`reg04_lkpsex`.`sex_des`,
                ' - ',
                IFNULL(`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`name`,
                        'Without name'),
                ' - ',
                IFNULL(`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`color`,
                        'Without color')) AS `animaldesc`
    FROM
        (`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`
        inner JOIN `adggtnz`.`reg04_lkpsex`)
    WHERE
        (((`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`sex` = `adggtnz`.`reg04_lkpsex`.`sex_cod`)
            AND (`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`sex` = 2)
            AND (NOT (`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`animalid` IN (SELECT DISTINCT
                `adggtnz`.`lng04_rpt_animdisp`.`tagid`FROM `adggtnz`.`lng04_rpt_animdisp`))))
            OR (((TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) - TO_DAYS(`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`birthdate`)) >= 558)
            AND (`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`sex` = 4))) 
            and reg04_rpt_animreg.animalid like '%000404018293'
```

the problem is that the query gives the wrong output instead of giving me  my animal as a Mature female it duplicates my record into four

```
'0755255400', 'TZN000404018293', '8293 - Mature male - None - Bl'
'0755255400', 'TZN000404018293', '8293 - Mature female - None - Bl'
'0755255400', 'TZN000404018293', '8293 - Male calf - None - Bl'
'0755255400', 'TZN000404018293', '8293 - Female calf - None - Bl'
```

when i remove the inner join of reg04_lkpsex i get the intended output. someone please help me modify my query to give me the correct out put

expected output

```
'0755255400', 'TZN000404018293', '8293 - Mature female - None - Bl'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
        `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`hh_id` AS `hh_id`,
        `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`animalid` AS `animalid`,
        CONCAT(IFNULL(`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`tagsec`,
                        'Without Tag'),
                ' - ',
                `adggtnz`.`reg04_lkpsex`.`sex_des`,
                ' - ',
                IFNULL(`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`name`,
                        'Without name'),
                ' - ',
                IFNULL(`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`color`,
                        'Without color')) AS `animaldesc`
FROM
        (`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`
        inner JOIN `adggtnz`.`reg04_lkpsex` on `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`sex` = `adggtnz`.`reg04_lkpsex`.`sex_cod`)
WHERE
        (((`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`sex` = 2)
            AND (NOT (`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`animalid` IN (SELECT DISTINCT
                `adggtnz`.`lng04_rpt_animdisp`.`tagid`FROM `adggtnz`.`lng04_rpt_animdisp`))))
            OR (((TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) - TO_DAYS(`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`birthdate`)) >= 558)
            and (`adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`sex` = 4))) 
            and `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`animalid`like '%000404018293'
```

this above query gives you the output of

```
'0755255400', 'TZN000404018293', '8293 - Female calf - None - Bl'
```

Comment: @janmyszkier please help me modify this query with the correct output but i need to change the output to my expected output

Answer (score 0):

add 

`` GROUP BY `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`animalid` ``

to it and it should be good

Comment: the output after you group by 

    '0755255400', 'TZN000404018293', '8293 - Mature male - None - Bl' @janmyszkier

Comment: then I'm afraid you'll have to provide CREATE TABLE for the desired table so I can analyze your WHERE, my guess is that's where you got your query wrong